# PHP Format string like a chemical formula

Tags: php

What is the best way to convert a string such as `CO2` and make it output `CO<sub>2</sub>` via PHP?

Comment: Are you sure you only want to subscript numbers?

Comment: How do you plan to determine what is what?

Comment: +1. Its going to difficult as you'd have to distinguish between numbers that need superscripting and those that need subscripting.

Comment: this seems an appropriate use for a regex replace http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `preg_replace()` to surround groups of digits with `<sub></sub>`

```
$input = "CO2";
echo preg_replace('/(\d+)/', '<sub>$1</sub>', $input);

// Using $input = "H2SO4";
// Prints:
H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>
```

Comment: +1 for beating me to the same answer. I was waiting on a *better* spec :)

Answer (score 3):

This will correctly *NOT* sub some of the digits.

```
$s = "O2+2H2=H2O";
$len = strlen($s);
$html = '';
if($len > 0) {
    $prev = $s[0];
    $html = $prev;
    for($i=1;$i<$len;$i++){
        $ch = $s[$i];
        if(is_numeric($ch) && 'a' <= strtolower($prev) && strtolower($prev) <= 'z') {
            $html .= "<sub>$ch</sub>";
        } else {
            $html .= $ch;
        }
        $prev = $ch;
    }
}
echo $html;
```

prints O<sub>2</sub>+2H<sub>2</sub>=H<sub>2</sub>O Note the non-sub-ed 2

Comment: lol got the formula wrong should be O2+2H2=2H2O but the code works.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)? It renders fomulars very nicely.
You could use it on your page by including

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://thewe.net/tex/textheworld6.user.js"></script>
```

and writing your fomular like this `[;CO_2;]` see [here](http://thewe.net/tex/).

Answer (score 1):

```
  //With ions in the equation:
   // charge written like: sign  number
$s= "1H2SO4=> 2H+1 + 1SO4-2 "    ;
//$s = "1O2  +  2H2=>  2H2O";
 $len = strlen($s);
 $html = '';
  if($len > 0) {
          $prev = $s[0];
          $html = $prev;
          for($i=1;$i<$len;$i++)
          {
              $ch = $s[$i];
              if(is_numeric($ch) && 'a' <= strtolower($prev) && strtolower($prev) <= 'z') 
                {  $html .= "<sub>$ch</sub>";   }

              else 
              {
                if(($ch=="+" or $ch=="-") && '1' <= strtolower($s[$i+1]) &&  strtolower($s[$i+1]) <= '9') 
                {
                    $html .= "<sup>$ch</sup>";
                    $html .= "<sup>".$s[$i+1]."</sup>";
                    $i=$i+1; 
               }
                  else
              {
                  $html .= $ch;
              }
              $prev = $ch;
             }      
           }
        }


echo $html;
```

Comment: Could you please explain in details what does this do? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be:

`preg_replace('/([A-Z)])([0-9]+)/', '\1<sub>\2</sub>', $input)`

That way you wouldn't have individual `<sub>` and `</sub>` around numbers higher than 9 next to each other (e.g., `<sub>12</sub>` and not `<sub>1</sub><sub>2</sub>`). It also accounts for parentheses and when you have numbers before the letters.

Comment: Exactly what I was was trying to do - saved a lot of debugging time.

Answer (score 0):

function formular($string){

```
    $string .= ' ';

    $len = strlen($string);

    $str_return = '';

    if($len > 0) {

        $prev       =    $string[0];
        $str_return =    $prev;

        for($i = 1; $i < $len; $i++){

            $ch = $string[$i];

            if(is_numeric($ch)){

                if('a' <= strtolower($prev) && strtolower($prev) <= 'z' || $prev == ')'){

                    if(( $string[$i+1]  == '-' || $string[$i+1]  == '+') && !in_array(@$string[$i+2], ['C', 'O', 'H'])){

                        $str_return .= '<sup>' . $ch . '</sup>';
                        $str_return .= '<sup>' . $string[$i+1] . '</sup>';
                        $i++;

                    }else{
                        $str_return .= "<sub>$ch</sub>";
                    }

                }else{

                    $str_return .= $ch;
                    $prev = $ch;
                }

            }else{

                $str_return .= $ch;
                $prev = $ch;
            }
        }
    }

    return $str_return;

}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer, but please note that just posting a block of code without any explanation is discouraged, as it does not do much to help the asker and potential other viewers understand how the problem was solved.